# knockout JS option data-bind multiple values

Tags: knockout.js

I would like to do add multiple values to the data-tokens attribute:

```
<option data-bind="text: customer_display_name, value: customer_id, attr: {'data-tokens': customer_first_name, customer_last_name}"></option>
```

Unfortunately this wont work, only the data-tokens "customer_first_name" works and the "customer_last_name" dont.
How can I add multiple valus?

EDIT:
I would also like to do the same inside an options binding:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true"
    data-bind="options: $parent.customers, optionsText: 'customer_display_name', optionsValue: 'customer_id', value: customer_id,
    event: {change: $parent.changeWorkCustomer}, attr: {'data-tokens': [$parent.customer_first_name, $parent.customer_last_name]}, css: { customer_fav: $parent.fav > 0 }">
```

It does not work like this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this also by wrapping them in an array and then `unwrap` by calling for their value:

```
data-bind="attr: {'data-tokens': [attr1(), attr2()]}
```

`ko` will figure out what needs to be done and output multiple values:

```js
function MyViewModel() {
  this.attr1 = ko.observable('test1')
  this.attr2 = ko.observable('test2')
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="attr: {'data-tokens': [attr1(), attr2()]}">Testing!</div>
<input type="text" data-bind="value: [attr1(), attr2()]" />
```

If you do `inspect element` on the `Testing!` you will see that the result is:

```
data-tokens="test1,test2"
```

Comment: perfect! This is exactly what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the values of both variables, with a comma in between?

Try this:

```
attr: {'data-tokens': (customer_first_name + ', ' + customer_last_name)}
```